# Creating obj with dynamically changeable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am going to create some count of object with specific names.

if i do

```
var obj = {}
obj.A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

that create key A with array value

Can I do something like this:

```
var obj = {}
var keyName = 'A';

obj.keyName = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

And obj containe name of key A and array as value.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
obj[keyName] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do like this below:

```
var obj = {}
var keyName = 'A';

obj.keyName = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

If you want to access the keyName value, you could do like this `obj[keyName] which would result in A` or set `obj[keyName] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`